# Optimizing UI Performance in SwiftUI macOS App with High-Resolution Images

Tags: swift, macos, performance, swiftui

I'm developing a SwiftUI application for macOS that loads and displays high-resolution images (2-3MB or larger) from a local source.

After these images are displayed, I've noticed a significant deterioration in the app's UI performance, such as laggy while using Slider or Textfield and delayed response to user interactions.

The issue seems to stem from the handling of these large resolution(over 2~3mb) image.

Here are the sample code used for loading and displaying the images:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedImageData: Data?
    @State private var sliderValue: Double = 50
    @State private var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("text", text: $text)
            Slider(value: $sliderValue, in: 0...100)
                .padding(.bottom, 50)
            Button("Choose Image") {
                openImagePicker()
            }
        }
        .background(
            Group {
                if let imageData = selectedImageData, let image = NSImage(data: imageData) {
                    Image(nsImage: image)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                } else {
                    Image(systemName: "photo")
                }
            }
        )
    }

    private func openImagePicker() {
        let panel = NSOpenPanel()
        panel.prompt = "Select Image"
        panel.allowedContentTypes = [.image, .png, .jpeg]
        panel.canChooseDirectories = false
        panel.canChooseFiles = true
        panel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        panel.begin { response in
            if response == .OK, let selectedURL = panel.urls.first, let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: selectedURL) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    selectedImageData = imageData
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The performance issues become apparent when these images are rendered on the screen,
using Slider or Textfield or when navigating through the app.**

I am looking for strategies or best practices to optimize the performance of a SwiftUI macOS app when handling and displaying high-resolution images.

thanks.

[image][image]

** lag disappear after separate image to other view. I think it's something to do with how swiftUI's screen updates behave on property updates, but I'm not sure exactly why yet..

```
struct BackgroundImageView: View {
    let imageData: Data?

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if let imageData = imageData, let image = NSImage(data: imageData) {
                Image(nsImage: image)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "photo")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What business does `Slider` have with the image you select with `NSOpenPanel`?  Whether you have an image selected or not, your typing will be interrupted while you use the slider.

Comment: Oh, there is no relationship.

I separated it into a separate view with BackgroundImageView(imageData: selectedImageData) and the lag went away.

I wonder if there was some relationship with the image when the UI (textfields and sliders, etc.) were updated.

Comment: What is the size of the image are you selecting at what DPI?  As long as I select a 1,400 x 900 px image @72 dpi, I don't see any performance issues.

Comment: Well, let me try with 1.6 MB image.

Comment: sample image was over 3 MB.

Comment: Okay.  I now see what you mean.  Sorry about that...  It's close to my bedtime.  I'll think about overnight.

Comment: The problem is that you are holding onto a large chunk of memory, which can be 200 MB or more, after you open a big image.  Unless you have a very good reason to show the entire image over the application window, only show a tiny thumbnail.

Comment: Regrettably, my application requires the use of large images. btw, Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Instead of dealing with Data directly try a URL so you can use AsyncImage. That will take the heavy lifting out of the View/MainActor.

Comment: What happens if you abstract the `background` into a separate `View`? I'd try structuring it so that once the data is loaded, it never recreates the `NSImage`. Right now, it recreates it on every view render.

Comment: is that same with BackGroundImageView at the end of the context doing what you said?

Comment: Could not replicate your issue, all works well for me in my tests. On MacOS 14.4, using Xcode 15.3, tested with a 5.2 MB image on a older iMac intel. What system are you using?

Comment: I'm using M1 - 14.3.1, Xcode - 15.2. it might be fixed in newer version.